# rails: style input with data-role set

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Ok so I am using [bootstrap-tagsinput](http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) to generate auto tagging inside my input.

The thing is that it is removing the style of the input. I could not find a way to change this. Any ideas ho to apply the current style to an input that has a data-role set?

```
<%= f.text_field :tag_list, placeholder: "Your favorite subject", id: "inputstyle",  class: "form-control", 'data-role': 'tagsinput' %>

#inputstyle {
  height: 43px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
  border: 3px solid #ecf0f1;
}
```